# Passing a bitmap from android camera to C++ with jni

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, bitmap

I have an application on which the user takes a photograph, and this gets returned to the java method in the form of a `Bitmap bitmap`. I want to pass this bitmap to a C++ function to do some OpenCV processing, as soon as it's been taken.

I'm having trouble finding the right data format to pass the bitmap into the method. I've tried passing the bitmap as a jobect parameter, but it didn't work.

Here is my jni method that i want to pass the bitmap into:

```
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_com_example_user_digitrecognition_MainActivity_generateAssets(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject assetManager) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access pixel buffer of `Bitmap` from jni, you can call [getPixels](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels(int[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)):

- `NewByteArray` an `byte[]` object (only needed to do once and GlobalRef/reused)
- FindClass/GetMethodID/CallVoidMethod to invoke the getPixels from c/c++
- `GetByteArrayRegion` to map the java `byte[]` to c buffer.

You can check JNI functions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html)

Or otherwise, manage the `byte[]` pixel buffer on Java side, and pass `byte[]` (and image format/dimension) to jni instead of `Bitmap` object. For example:

```
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_com_example_user_digitrecognition_jniFacility_handleFrame(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject self, jobject pixels, jint width, jint height, jint format) {
    ...
}
```

Since you said you got the `Bitmap`, to pass bitmap to jni:

```
pixels = new byte[width * height * 4]; // assume RGBA, do once only
...
bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
handleFrame(pixels, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
```

For best performance (and live recording), you may want to use `ImageReader` and work with YUV image instead.

---

By the way, opencv accept `ImageFormat.YUV_420_888` if you are getting frames by ImageReader. And you probably want to resize and just use the luminance channel for most processing.

Comment: How do i pass the image format/dimension to jni like you mentioned in the last line? Which format should I use?

Comment: @Ber12345 updated answer for your query, note that if you got the image as `Bitmap`, presumably from intent, you have no control over the format and you need to manually convert it using image utility functions.